# Wallpaper goes back to default after restarting the computer

Tags: desktop-background

I'm new to Ubuntu,installed it a few days ago after a friend recommended it to me.So far so good,I like it and everything is fine with it,except for one problem.It isn't a major problem,but I'd be happy to get it fixed.The wallpaper always goes back to the default one after I shut down or restart the computer.The thing is that the wallpaper that I selected over the default one is still selected in the "Appearance" panel,so it's not like the setting isn't saved or something.Also,when I enter there to change the wallpaper,it goes back to the one that I was using.I only have to enter there and without touching anything,it changes back to mine.

Long story short: I change the wallpaper,I restart/shut down,the wallpaper is back to the default one and if I enter "Appearance",it automatically goes back to the one i had,without me re-selecting it.

Any way to make it stay after restart/shut down without me always going to "Appearance" ?

Comment: Are you using own background image, or one that's available under appearance?

Comment: What Ubuntu **version**? What graphics chip/board?

Comment: Nevermind,I sorted it out.The problem was that the picture I was using was on another hard disk,not on the one which had Ubuntu installed.Moved it on the Ubuntu one and it works now.

Answer (score -1):

Copy your picture/wallpaper into ubuntu root,desktop or any direction within ubuntu installation disk

Because when you start ubuntu you have to mound these drives if not then ubuntu can't access the data of that drives.